# 1st order pde and lagrange method.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Consider the first order  Partial differential equation (Which is actually Invischid Burger's equation)

$$u_{t}+u(x,t)u_x{}=0$$

With the initial condition ,

$$u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.$$ Then,

$(a)$ Show that there exists $t>0$, such that the problem has unique   solution in the strip

$$\mathbb{R} \times (0,t),$$

$(b)$ Show that there may not exist solutions for the strip

$\mathbb{R} \times (0,\infty)$,

$(c)$ Also find a $t'$ such that for $\epsilon \gt0$, there exists solution in $\mathbb{R}\times (0,t')$ but not in 
        $\mathbb{R} \times (0,t'+\epsilon).$

Answer (score 1):

By Lagrange's Theorem,

$$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac {dx}{u}=\frac{du}{0}$$

So, from the first and last equation,
   $$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{du}{0}$$
  or,$$u(x,t)=c$$
Similarly, from the first and second equation,
  $$ \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{u},$$
 or, $$\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{c},$$
  Integrating, we get
    $$x=c\times {t}+d $$
  Hence $$x-u\times{t}=d$$

so,

$$u(x,t)=f(x-ut)$$

initially,

$$u(x,0)=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$$

so, $$u(x,t)= \frac{1}{1+(x-ut)^{2}}$$

Comment: Thanks for editing my question . I learned clearity